# Folder chooser on Windows

Tags: windows, qt, directory, qt5, folderbrowserdialog

How can I call the folder default windows folder chooser.

I'm using the call:

`QString path = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(parent, "", folder, QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly);`

But this call show the dialog below:

[image: Showed dialog]

How can I choose this dialog as folder chooser?

[image: Expected dialog]

Comment: You can make a dialog with QTreeView http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html

Comment: There is no simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did everything correctly. I just tested this on an XP with Qt 4.7.0 and it works as you expect but when testing on Windows 8 with Qt 5.0.2, I get the ordinary file open dialog.

I suggest you log this as a bug.

Comment: I'm using Qt 5 on Windows 7