# Folder chooser with filetree layout

Tags: java

I want to create a directory selector in Java, but when doing this using the JFileChooser and set it to `DIRECTORIES-ONLY`, you get an unclear layout of the folders (just a normal FileChooser layout). For folders however I think its more useful to show a filetree showing all directories with the main disk as root, like a normal windows filechooser (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741881/folder-chooser-on-windows) post, this guy wants to do the same thing but not in Java).

Is there some way to do this without writing it myself (preferably not with external libraries)?

Comment: You can try extending the existing code, if the class isn't marked `final`.  The you can overwrite the drawing methods to draw whatever you want/need.  Otherwise, you have to roll-your-own.

Comment: So are you saying that it is not possible without writing alot of code myself?

Comment: I am saying I do not believe it's possible to customize the JFileChooser without doing some code.  How much depends on if you can simply extend the existing class and modify how it's drawing.

Comment: BTW, this posting on SO might be of some use:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720957/creating-custom-jfilechooser